# Python Cryptography: Cannot sign with RSA private key using PKCS1v15 padding

Tags: php, python, cryptography, pkcs#1

I'm trying to implement a functionally equivalent signing with Python and the Cryptography library to PHP's `openssl_pkey_get_private` and `openssl_sign` using a SHA1 hash. I've read that PHP uses PKCS1v15 padding, so that's what I'm trying to use as well. My code is:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

pk = open('key.pem', 'rb')
key = load_pem_private_key(pk.read(), password=None, backend=default_backend())
message = b'hello world'
signature = key.sign(
    message,
    padding.PKCS1v15,
    hashes.SHA1()
)
```

Executing this results in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-ef3db8a6f4a8> in <module>()
      3     message,
      4     padding.PKCS1v15,
----> 5     hashes.SHA1()
      6 )

/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py in sign(self, data, padding, algorithm)
    613 
    614     def sign(self, data, padding, algorithm):
--> 615         signer = self.signer(padding, algorithm)
    616         signer.update(data)
    617         signature = signer.finalize()

/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py in signer(self, padding, algorithm)
    550 
    551     def signer(self, padding, algorithm):
--> 552         return _RSASignatureContext(self._backend, self, padding, algorithm)
    553 
    554     def decrypt(self, ciphertext, padding):

/home/vagrant/virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py in __init__(self, backend, private_key, padding, algorithm)
    170 
    171         if not isinstance(padding, AsymmetricPadding):
--> 172             raise TypeError("Expected provider of AsymmetricPadding.")
    173 
    174         self._pkey_size = self._backend._lib.EVP_PKEY_size(

TypeError: Expected provider of AsymmetricPadding.
```

Comment: What version of cryptography lib are you using?

Comment: We tried with versions 1.4 and 1.5.

Comment: Have you tried with PSS padding ? Also it is not recommended to use PKCS1v15 padding for newer application due to vulnerability. Refer https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.padding.PKCS1v15

Comment: If `padding.PKCS1v15` is supposed to be an instance, shouldn't you use parentheses as well, i.e. `padding.PKCS1v15()`?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, thank you! That solved the issue. If you write your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator `isinstance` indicates that `padding.PKCS1v15` needs to be an instance instead of the type (class) itself. That means that the object instance should be created by calling the constructor.

To do this add parentheses, i.e. `padding.PKCS1v15()`.